# Power BI exchange rate calculation

Tags: date, dynamic, powerbi-desktop, currency-exchange-rates

I am a newbie in Power BI desktop.
We have a Sales transaction table with RateDate, orderAmount and transaction Currency

[image]

Also, we have an exchange rate table with BaseCurrency(standard currency i.e. USD,EUR and INR) ,target currency, effective date and Rate.

[image]

For analysis, We need to convert the Salesamount in any of the Base Currency i.e USD/INR/EUR as per the rate date-effective date mapping on the fly.
How can I achieve that?

I tried following DAX code,

```
AmountUSD = SUMX(Fact_SalesOrder,[OrderAmount]/lookupvalue(CurrencyRates[Rate],CurrencyRates[Effective Date],Fact_SalesOrder[RateDate],CurrencyRates[Base Currency],"USD",CurrencyRates[Target Currency],Fact_SalesOrder[Currency]))
```

But it results in 'infinity' value.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it :)

Just need 2 measures: SalesAmount for Sales and Selected currency for selection.

```
Selected Currency = VALUES('ReportingCurrencies'[Currency])
```

And

```
SalesAmount = SWITCH(TRUE(),
[Selected Currency] = "EUR",SUMX(Fact_SalesOrder,[OrderAmount]/lookupvalue(CurrencyRates[Rate],CurrencyRates[Effective Date].[Date],Fact_SalesOrder[RateDate].[Date],CurrencyRates[Base Currency],"EUR",CurrencyRates[Target Currency],Fact_SalesOrder[Currency],1)),
[Selected Currency] = "USD",SUMX(Fact_SalesOrder,[OrderAmount]/lookupvalue(CurrencyRates[Rate],CurrencyRates[Effective Date].[Date],Fact_SalesOrder[RateDate].[Date],CurrencyRates[Base Currency],"USD",CurrencyRates[Target Currency],Fact_SalesOrder[Currency],1)),
[Selected Currency] = "INR",SUMX(Fact_SalesOrder,[OrderAmount]/lookupvalue(CurrencyRates[Rate],CurrencyRates[Effective Date].[Date],Fact_SalesOrder[RateDate].[Date],CurrencyRates[Base Currency],"INR",CurrencyRates[Target Currency],Fact_SalesOrder[Currency],1)))
```